# Rectangle Tool Image Change Run Time

Tags: activex, teechart

I have added rectangle tool which contain an Image. The feature I want to develop is on right Click I want to change the image in it.

I tried using OnRectangleToolClick but not able to get the rectangle tool details which has been clicked.

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple example with VB6:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()      
  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 8

  TChart1.Tools.Add tcRectangle
  TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asRectangle.Shape.Picture.LoadImage "C:\tmp\MyImage.jpg"
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnRectangleToolClick(ByVal Button As TeeChart.EMouseButton, ByVal Shift As TeeChart.EShiftState, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
  If Button = mbRight Then
    MsgBox "Rectangle clicked with the right mouse button"
  End If
End Sub
```

The above seems not to work fine, but after debugging I've seen when I click on the rectangle tool with the right mouse button and `TChart1_OnRectangleToolClick` is fired, the `Button` variable has the value 1, while `mbRight` is 2. So changing it for this makes it work:

```
Private Sub TChart1_OnRectangleToolClick(ByVal Button As TeeChart.EMouseButton, ByVal Shift As TeeChart.EShiftState, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
  If Button = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Rectangle clicked with the right mouse button"
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you want to check when the user clicks the Rectangle tool with the left mouse button, the `OnRectangleToolClick` event may conflict with the dragging feature.
In that case, you could still play with `OnMouseMove`, `OnClick` and `OnMouseDown` events as in the following example:

```
Dim mouseXPos, mouseYPos, mouseXDown, mouseYDown As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()      
  TChart1.AddSeries scBar
  TChart1.Series(0).FillSampleValues 8

  TChart1.Tools.Add tcRectangle
  TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asRectangle.Shape.Picture.LoadImage "C:\tmp\MyImage.jpg"

  mouseXPos = -1
  mouseYPos = -1
  mouseXDown = -1
  mouseYDown = -1
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnMouseMove(ByVal Shift As TeeChart.EShiftState, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
  mouseXPos = X
  mouseYPos = Y
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnClick()
  If mouseXDown = mouseXPos And mouseYDown = mouseYPos Then
    If TChart1.Tools.Items(0).asRectangle.Clicked(mouseXPos, mouseYPos) Then
      MsgBox "Rectangle clicked with the left mouse button"
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnMouseDown(ByVal Button As TeeChart.EMouseButton, ByVal Shift As TeeChart.EShiftState, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
  mouseXDown = X
  mouseYDown = Y
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use left click instead of right click for changing the image ,the issue is even if I try to drag the rectangle tool it first call is onRectangleToolCick and changes the images which should not happen since I am dragging the tool

Comment: I've just edited the answer replying your last comment